# Ambiguity in the evaluation of a real integral multiplied by a complex number

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let's consider the following integral, where x is a real value: $\int_{0}^{1}ln(i)x^{2}dx=i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}dx$. Since $ln(i)=i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$, k being an integer, what value should I consider?

Comment: Define $\ln (i)$.

Answer (score 1):

In complex analysis, the logarithm is what we call a multivalued function, and you need to do what is called a branch cut in order for it to be a well defined function. The "standard" is what we call the principal branch, often denoted $\text{Log}$, where the argument is chosen within the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$. However, other choices may be beneficial or even necessary in certain situations.

You can read more about the complex logarithm here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Principal_value) section discusses the principal value, which in this problem corresponds to $k=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read about principal values, but I'm still confused about what should I do with that integral. In fact, the integral I wrote is just a part of a bigger calculation in which I started from a real integral, then turned it into a complex one (as in the integrand the real variable x was multiplied by an imaginary expression) and solved it. Now, since the integrand from which I started is real, I would expect to obtain a real answer (and this happens only if I consider the principle value). Does this allow me to claim that k=0?

Comment: That is difficult to say only based on the information that you have provided. However, assuming that all you have done up to this point is correct, that would be natural, yes! If you're solving a real integral, you should definitely arrive at a real answer.